# All possible combinations of elements

Tags: combinations

I'd like to know a possible algorithm to calculate all possible combinations, without repetitions, starting from length=1 until length=N of N elements.

Example:

Elements: 1, 2, 3.

Output:

```
1
2
3
12
13
23
123
```

Comment: It sounds like you want the power set...see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set

Comment: All combinations independent of ordering?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at the binary presentation of the numbers 0 to 2^n - 1.

```
n = 3

i  Binary  Combination

   CBA

0  000
1  001     A
2  010       B
3  011     A B
4  100         C
5  101     A   C
6  110       B C
7  111     A B C
```

So you just have to enumerate the numbers 1 to 2^n - 1 and look at the binary representation to know which elements to include. If you want to have them ordered by the number of elements post sort them or generate the numbers in order (there are several example on SO).

Comment: Thank you ! so simple... i didn't think to it at all.

Thanks again