# Generate All Unique Combinations of Elements of a IEnumerable(Of T)

Tags: .net, vb.net, algorithm, combinatorics

This question is virtually the same as [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471558/all-possible-combinations-of-elements), only I'm looking for a VB.NET (.NET 4) solution.  I've spun my wheels long enough trying to come up with a generic solution to solving this "power set" problem.

Given:

```
Dim choices As IEnumerable(Of String) = {"Coffee", "Tea", "Milk", "Cookies"}
Dim choiceSets = choices.CombineAll()
```

I'm looking for `choiceSets` to be an `IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T))` so that I can do something like:

```
For each choiceSet in choiceSets
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", choiceSet))
Next
```

And get results that look like:

```
Coffee
Tea
Milk
Cookies
Coffee, Tea
Coffee, Milk
Coffee, Cookies
Tea, Milk
Tea, Cookies
Milk, Cookies
Coffee, Tea, Milk
Coffee, Tea, Cookies
Coffee, Milk, Cookies
Tea, Milk, Cookies
Coffee, Tea, Milk, Cookies
```

As you can see, this is every *non-repeating* combination from the source `IEnumerable(Of T)` (which could have 1 to many items in it - this example only had 4), it operates based on the order of the items in the source `IEnumerable(Of T)`, and each item in the list is >= the previous item in terms of number of items in the inner `IEnumerable(Of T)`.

For what it's worth, this is not homework; though it sure does feel like it.

EDIT: Updated the example so it does not look like the result is alphabetically sorted, to stress that the source `IEnumerable(Of T)`'s existing order is used and added a 4th choice to clarify the sorting requirement within each set.

Comment: Note that IEnumerable<T> does not guarantee consistent ordering, so "honoring" it might differ from call to call.

Comment: @dlev That's notable, thanks.  I think the question could still stand with the (false) assumption that IEnumerable<T> does guarantee consistent ordering.  Let's just pretend it does for simplicity sake :)

Comment: You might try the code sample in here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx

Comment: @mellamokb Thanks for the link.  I actually did see that article's code when I started researching for this.  It seemed to me to be an overly complex solution, especially when I've seen examples of similar combinatorial problems done in self-contained extensions.  My fallback solution to this problem is indeed that article's solution if no one else can come up with something a bit less bulky.

Comment: Note that what you want is called the "power set" of a set; the set of all the subsets. (The power set also includes the empty subset, which you omit.)  If you're searching for solutions to this problem, knowing its right name will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a pure Linq solution, inspired by Eric Lippert's [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx) about computing a cartesian product. I modified the `CartesianProduct` method slightly so that it returns combinations:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    return sequences.Aggregate(
        emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) => 
        from accseq in accumulator 
        // Exclude items that were already picked
        from item in sequence.Except(accseq)
        // Enforce ascending order to avoid same sequence in different order
        where !accseq.Any() || Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(item, accseq.Last()) > 0
        select accseq.Concat(new[] {item})).ToArray();
}
```

Based on this extension method, you can produce the desired result as follows:

```cs
IEnumerable<string> items = new[] {"Coffee", "Tea", "Milk"};
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> result =
    Enumerable.Range(1, items.Count())
        .Aggregate(
            Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<string>>(),
            (acc, i) =>
                acc.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(items, i).Combinations()));
```

(it concatenates all combinations of 1, 2... N items)

Note that it's probably not a very efficient solution, but I think it's an interesting use of Linq...

---

EDIT: here's a new version of the `Combinations` method that maintains the original order:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    var indexedSequences = sequences.Select(seq => seq.Select((item, idx) => new IndexedItem<T>(item, idx)));
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IndexedItem<T>>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<IndexedItem<T>>() };
    var indexedResult =
        indexedSequences.Aggregate(
            emptyProduct,
            (accumulator, sequence) => 
            from accseq in accumulator 
            // Exclude items that were already picked
            from item in sequence.Except(accseq)
            // Enforce ascending order of indexes to avoid same sequence in different order
            where !accseq.Any() || item.Index > accseq.Last().Index
            select accseq.Concat(new[] {item})).ToArray();
    return indexedResult.Select(seq => seq.Select(i => i.Item));
}

class IndexedItem<T>
{
    public IndexedItem(T item, int index)
    {
        this.Item = item;
        this.Index = index;
    }

    public T Item { get; private set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

Probably even more inefficient than the previous version, but it gets the job done...

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Correct number of results (and I like that it didn't even include the empty set), but the ordering doesn't satisfy the problem statement, but it is VERY close (closest answer yet).  The ordering rules noticeably break down once a 4th item is added to 'items.'  The results are ordered properly from top to bottom, but are not ordered properly within the set.  I could do some post-processing ordering to get them back in the correct order.

Comment: @ckittel, see my updated answer. I associated an index with each item so that I can maintain the original order

Comment: A+.  Thank you so much! This solution is ideal for my needs.  I'll probably write up an answer myself later today to show the VB.NET version for others' benefit, but this solution is definitely the accepted answer.  Thanks for being so diligent in your solution.

Answer (score 2):

In case it's of use to anyone else, I've converted the original C# extension Thomas Levesque posted to VB.NET:

```
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function Combinations(Of T)(ByVal sequences As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T))) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T))
        Dim seed As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T)) = {  Enumerable.Empty(Of T) }
        Dim r = sequences.Aggregate(seed, 
             Function(ByVal accumulator, ByVal sequence) _
               From accseq In accumulator    _
               From item In sequence.Except(accseq) _
               Where (Not accseq.Any()) OrElse Comparer(Of T).Default.Compare(item, accseq.Last()) > 0  _
               Select accseq.Concat(  {item}  ) ).ToArray()
        Return r
    End Function
```

It's a bit awkward usage to have to call Repeat n times to generate a repeated Enumerable containing the set of all possible values n times, where n is the number of elements in each resulting unique combination of T, but it gets the job done.  Order of the results didn't matter for me, so I didn't convert the 'indexed' version posted later.

Here's my usage of the extension, which operates on an array of Integers instead of Strings, and gets me the 'empty' set with no elements in it and the 'full' (or original) set

```
    Dim allRolesArray  = {1,4,5,2,0}
    Dim comboCountValues = Enumerable.Range(0, allRolesArray.Count()+1)
    Dim allRoleCombos = comboCountValues.Aggregate(
        Enumerable.Empty(Of IEnumerable(Of Integer))(),
        Function (acc, i) acc.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(allRolesArray, i).Combinations() ) ).ToList
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another [approach here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42375146-eade-43ae-9550-1dfdd7c8aa18/how-to-get-power-set-) (look there for C# code).

```
    Public Function GetPowerSet(Of T)(items As IEnumerable(Of T)) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T))

         Dim result = From m In Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << items.Count)
                 Select
                    From i In Enumerable.Range(0, items.Count)
                    Where (m And (1 << i)) <> 0
                        Select items(i)
         Return result

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A naive recursive solution (lots of list creation overhead):

```
    static List<IEnumerable<string>> GetChoiceSets(IEnumerable<string> choices)
    {
        if (choices == null || !choices.Any())
            return null;
        else
        {
            var first = choices.Take(1);
            var inner = GetChoiceSets(choices.Skip(1));

            if (inner == null)
                return new List<IEnumerable<string>> { first, new List<string> { } };
            else
                return inner.Select(lst => first.Union(lst)).Union(inner).ToList();
        }
    }
```

A slightly less naive iterative solution using the linked SO algorithm:

```
    static List<List<string>> GetChoiceSets2(List<string> choices)
    {
        int capacity = (int)Math.Pow(2, choices.Count());
        int bit = 1;
        List<List<string>> choiceSets = new List<List<string>>(capacity);
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
            choiceSets.Add(new List<String>());

        for (int i = 0; i < choices.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < capacity; n++)
            {
                if ((n & bit) == bit)
                    choiceSets[n].Add(choices[i]);
            }
            bit *= 2;
        }

        return choiceSets;
    }
```

These could probably both be improved, but depending on the size of the sets in use, one or the other should be efficient enough.

Comment: Thanks, good start.  The first solution isn't returning them in the order specified, where the sets increase in size (or remain unchanged in size) and retain order.  I'm getting [Coffee, Tea, Milk], [Coffee, Tea], [Coffee, Milk], [Coffee], [Tea, Milk], [Tea], [Milk], []. (plus a blank item at the end?)  I'll try out the second solution to see if that follows the necessary requirements.

Comment: Looks like the second solution suffers from the same ordering requirements gap (and also has the blank item on the end).  In both cases, the correct values are indeed being found, the ordering is just off-spec.

Answer (score 0):

I don't program in VB.NET, and this is just typed in.  So there may be serious bugs.  But the approach should work.

```
static List<List<string>> GetChoiceSets(List<string> choices)
{
    int capacity = (int) Math.Pow(2, choices.Count()) - 1;
    int bit = 1;
    List<List<string>> choiceSets = new List<List<string>>(capacity);
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        choiceSets.Add(new List<String>());

    n = 0;
    for (int size = 1; size <= choices.Count(); size++)
    {
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            indexes.Add(i);

        // We break out after exhausting all sets of this size.
        for (;;) {
            // Insert solution.
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                choiceSets[n].Add(choices[indexes[i]]);
            n++;

            // Figure out the first place we can advance indexes.
            int j = 1;
            for (; j <= size; j++) {
                if (indexes[size - j] < choices.Count() - j) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            threshold = choices.Count() - j
            // Did we finish?
            if (threshold < 0)
                break;

            // We will increment the index at threshold, and make following ones
            // increment from there.
            indexes[threshold]++;
            for (int i = 1; i + threshold < choices.Count(); i++)
                indexes[threshold + i] = indexes[threshold] + i;
        }
    }

    return choiceSets;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> seed = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<string>() };

choices.Aggregate(
    seed,
    (acc, item) =>
        acc.SelectMany(a => new[] { a, a.Concat(new[] {item}) }))
```

or

```
choices.Aggregate(
    seed,
    (acc, item) =>
        from a in acc
        from c in new[] { Enumerable.Empty<string>(), new[] { item } }
        select a.Concat(c))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Correct number of results, but the ordering doesn't satisfy the problem statement.  Vastly different matter of fact, especially when you start adding more than three items in 'choices.'