# Find all subsets with Enumerable.Zip or bitwise AND logic

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, bit-manipulation, subset

I wanted to find all subsets of an array of integers, so my first thought was to use the binary representation of numbers of size n bits, where 1 includes and 0 doesn't include.

For example:

```
int[] arr = { 3, 4, 5 };
```

going through numbers 0 to 7 gives me:

```
0,0,0
0,0,1
0,1,0
0,1,1
1,0,0
...etc
```

this maps to:

```
empty
5
4
4,5
3
...etc
```

To do the mapping I used Enumerable.Zip. The code is:

```
public static IEnumerable<byte> ToBinary(this int value, int size)
{
    return ToBinaryStream(value, size).Reverse();
}

private static IEnumerable<byte> ToBinaryStream(int value, int size)
{
    if (value < 0)
        yield break;
    do
    {
        yield return (byte)(value & 1);
        --size;
    }
    while ((value = value >> 1) > 0 || size > 0);
}

int?[] arr = { 1,2,3,4 };

List<int[]> subsets = new List<int[]>();

for (int i = 0; i < (int)Math.Pow(2, (arr.Length)); i++)
{
    var subset = i.ToBinary(arr.Length).Zip(arr, (value, array) => value == 1 ? array : null)
        .Where(a => a != null).Cast<int>().ToArray();
    subsets.Add(subset);
}
```

Seems to work great. Question is how can I use bitwise AND logic to do the same thing?

I want to map 1000 to the first element in the array, and 1001 to the first and last etc.

Comment: This is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980810/generate-all-unique-combinations-of-elements-of-a-ienumerableof-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if an element `x` with index `i` should be included for a number `num`:

1. Shift 1 left by `i`
2. Bitwise AND the result with `num`
3. If the result is greater than 0, include `x`

Here's the code:

```
int[] arr = { 1,2,3,4 };

List<int[]> subsets = Enumerable
              .Range(0, (int)Math.Pow(2, (arr.Length)))
              .Select(num => arr.Where((x, i) => ((1 << i) & num) > 0).ToArray())
              .ToList();
```

It treats the lowest bit in `num` as the first element in the array to avoid having to reverse things.  Interesting idea by the way :)

Comment: just what I was looking for!